# About the paper 'Exponential Communication Complexity Advantage from Quantum Superposition of the Direction of Communication'

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

In a recent paper ['Exponential Communication Complexity Advantage from Quantum Superposition of the Direction of Communication'](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.07372), the authors claimed that by superpositioning two different trajectories of the communication, an exponential communication complexity advantage can be achieved for a designed communication task.

Here I have my question:

In the paper, they assumed that the communication is 'one-way', only from A to B, or only from B to A, so to achieve the goal, A/B must send one of the two functions (f or g) to the counterpart, so the complexity is $2^n$.

But in the later SWITCH-based configuration, in fact both the communication routes A->B and B->A are allowed. So A/B only need to exchange the data (x/y processed by f/g) but not the functions f/g, therefore an exponential complexity advantage is achieved.

For me, this seems break the assumption of the communication task (physically the communication is bi-directional, A->B & B->A). Can anybody help to clarify this?

For me, it seems that if we assume that A can only send information to B (A is in the causal past of B), then the only way to send information from B to A is by time travel mechanism such as the 'radio-to-the-past' link achieved by closed timelike curves.

Comment: Can you not simply assume the B->A channel is completely independent of the A->B channel?

Comment: I do not get you. If the SWITCH based strategy can be achieved, then a non-SWITCH based configuration can also be achieved with a polynomial complexity cost as shown in 'Quantum computation with programmable connections between gates'.